# Special ordering

Tags: oracle, order-by

I have a hierarchical query but I don't manage to order it as I want.

I have a column named sequence that indicates how to order it but the data is kinda mixed up and I cant do it properly.

This a lookalike of the information I have:

```
ID      | Sequence | Parent_ID |   text
145     | 1        |  NULL     |'1. INFORMATION'
146     | 2        |  NULL     |'2. MORE INFORMATION'
147     | 3        |  NULL     |'3. EVEN MORE'
148     | 1        |  147      |'  1. INFORMATION LVL2 FOR PARENT 3'
149     | 2        |  147      |'  2. INFORMATION LVL2 FOR PARENT 3'
150     | 4        |  NULL     |'4. EVEN MORE'
151     | 1        |  146      |'  1. INFORMATION LVL2 FOR PARENT 2'
```

If I run the query without ordering I end up with information like this:

```
ID      | Sequence | Parent_ID |   text
148     | 4        |  NULL     |'4. EVEN MORE'
145     | 1        |  NULL     |'1. INFORMATION'
147     | 3        |  NULL     |'3. EVEN MORE'
149     | 1        |  147      |'  1. INFORMATION LVL2 FOR PARENT 3'
150     | 2        |  147      |'  2. INFORMATION LVL2 FOR PARENT 3'
146     | 2        |  NULL     |'2. MORE INFORMATION'
151     | 1        |  146      |'  1. INFORMATION LVL2 FOR PARENT 2'
```

currently I have in place an ORDER BY id, sequence but that sends the second level item of the parent 146 to the last position looking just like the first set of data.

is there a way to order it to put that lost node 151 under its parent 146 without messing up all the other information?

This is more or less what I need as end result:

```
ID      | Sequence | Parent_ID |   text
145     | 1        |  NULL     |'1. INFORMATION'
146     | 2        |  NULL     |'2. MORE INFORMATION'
151     | 1        |  146      |'  1. INFORMATION LVL2 FOR PARENT 2'
147     | 3        |  NULL     |'3. EVEN MORE'
148     | 1        |  147      |'  1. INFORMATION LVL2 FOR PARENT 3'
149     | 2        |  147      |'  2. INFORMATION LVL2 FOR PARENT 3'
150     | 4        |  NULL     |'4. EVEN MORE'
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Oracle 9i and 10g... I have this same behavior in both versions

Comment: Can you post the exact result that you want with your example data?

Comment: In the end I expect to have something like this; the child item with id 151 should go after the parent item 146.

Comment: Edit your post with it, rather than relying on a craply formatted comment

Comment: Can there be more than 2 levels in the hierarchy?

Comment: yes, it vareies but it can have up to 5 levels that I've seen and the system that uses it can go beyond 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could post the actual query you're running.  Even better would be if you created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so that we can play around with your data and your tables.

It appears, however, that you simply want to replace your `ORDER BY` clause with

```
ORDER SIBLINGS BY sequence
```

As an example, if you want to report on the `EMP` table and list the reports in alphabetical order, here is [an example of the `ORDER BY SIBLINGS`](http://www.oracledba.co.uk/tips/9i_siblings.htm) clause

Comment: Yep, that solves the issue. Thanks; this is my first time arround, Next time I'll try to use more propper tools to explain... I already saved the URL to add a SQL Fiddle